# Ubuntu KVM Guest DNS problems

Tags: 14.04, networking, dns, kvm-virtualization

I have a DNS problem in a KVM guest running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. The host is the same. The host has a bridge network configured since I want to see the guest on my network.

So far, I can see the guest on my network. I can ping it. The guest can ping out without problem. The guest has a static IP configured. I can ping external DNS servers etc.

The problem is that DNS just does not work on the guest. I cannot resolve anything either using nslookup or host commands.

The host does not have any DNS issues.

So I am baffled as to why DNS does not work but networking does.

Here is the host `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto em1
iface em1 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
   address 192.168.1.150
   network 192.168.1.0
   broadcast 192.168.1.255
   gateway 192.168.1.6
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   dns-nameservers 206.248.154.170 206.248.154.22
   bridge_ports em1
   bridge_stp off
   bridge_fd 0
   bridge_maxwait 0
```

Here is the `ifconfig` of the guest:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:3e:7a:56:f5
          inet addr:192.168.1.151  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::216:3eff:fe7a:56f5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:215 errors:0 dropped:17 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:58 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:17545 (17.5 KB)  TX bytes:7237 (7.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:52 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:52 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:4568 (4.5 KB)  TX bytes:4568 (4.5 KB)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The resolver looks in `/etc/resolv.conf` for nameservers, not `/etc/network/interfaces`. Create `/etc/resolv.conf` containing:

```
nameserver 206.248.154.170
nameserver 206.248.154.22
```

Manual pages:

- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/interfaces.5.html
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/resolv.conf.5.html

Comment: Technically I should not edit /etc/resolv.conf but rather /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base and then perform sudo resolvconf -u. But I get your meaning. This however does not resolve the issue as I was specifying the server in nslookup before. But thanks anyways. I still have the DNS issue.

Comment: @garthoid `nslookup example.com 206.248.154.170` times out for me (whereas `nslookup example.com 8.8.8.8` for Google DNS works). Is this some ISP DNS server not accessible to the outside world?

Comment: 206.248.154.170 is the DNS servers for my ISP. For example, on my **host** I can  `nslookup askubuntu.com 206.248.154.170` and it successfully returns the domain information. However on my **guest** it fails. Also, `nslookup askubuntu.com 8.8.8.8` times out on my guest yet I can `ping 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 1):

Bingo! I found it. It took some faffing about (a technical term) but I was able to eventual get the brain working.

Here is what I know. Networking based on IP address is fine. I can ping out and ping in. So TCP generally is not a problem in this bridged KVM guest. Yet dns, regardless of the server was an issue. Why? If networking is generally fine but a particular service is having an issue then I should have naturally decided to look at the firewall.

In this case, the **host** firewall was blocking DNS requests from the guess. Since this is an internal system disabling the **host** firewall with:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

and opening up iptables:

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -X
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

...resolved my issue. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Make sure to mark this as the answer, so people can refer to it at a later point, and have an easy visual cue. =P

Comment: I will have to wait for tomorrow to accept my own answer. It will not allow me to accept it today. Cooling off period? :-)